# How to uncapture the range of elements in for loop using PHP?

Tags: php

Example:

```
@article{boonzaier2009development,<br/>
 author = "Boonzaier, A. and Schubach, K. and Troup, K. and Pollard, A. and Aranda, S. and  Schofield, P.",<br/>
 title = "Development of a psychoeducational intervention ",<br/>
 journal = "Journal of Psychosocial Oncology",<br/>
 volume = "27",<br/>
 number = "1",<br/>
 pages = "136-153",<br/>
 year = 2009<br/>
}<br/>

@book{bottoff2008women,<br/>
  author = "Bottoff, J. L. and Oliffe, J. L. and Halpin, M. and Phillips, M. and McLean, G. and Mroz, L.",<br/>
  title = "Women and prostate cancer support groups: {The} gender connect? {Social} {Science} & {Medicine}",<br/>
  publisher = "66",<br/>
  pages = "1217-1227",<br/>
  year = 2008<br/>
}<br/>

@article{bottorff2012gender,<br/>
 author = "Bottorff, J. L. and Oliffe, J. L. and Kelly, M.",<br/>
 title = "The gender (s) in the room",<br/>
 journal = "Qualitative Health Research",<br/>
 volume = "22",<br/>
 number = "4",<br/>
 pages = "435-440",<br/>
 year = 2012<br/>
}
```

I want to capture the string between double quotes of @article part only. Am getting the count of @article and range of @article fields to get the values of @article elements. Using for loop am getting values of @article (for loop values: range of @article to next @article and so on) The problem is, for example first string @article is in 10th line and second one is in 18 th line, am doing for loop between this range and getting the value but, inbetween @book also is there so how to eliminate that @book range of lines in for loop. Because it captures @book elements also as it is inside in the range of @article.

php code:

```
<?php
$file=file("master.bib");
$typeart=array();
$cont=array();

//count of article
$key = '@article';
foreach ($file as $l => $line) {
    if (strpos($line,$key) !== false) {
       $l++;
       $typeart[]= $l;

          }
}//end-count of article

$counttypeart=count($typeart);

for($j=0;$j<$counttypeart;$j++){

    for($i=$typeart[$j];$i<$typeart[$j+1];$i++){
if(strpos($file[$i],'author')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$author= $cont[1];
echo $author;
echo "<br>";    
}   
if(strpos($file[$i],'title')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$title= $cont[1];
echo $title;
echo "<br>";
}
if(strpos($file[$i],'journal')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$journal= $cont[1];
echo $journal;
echo "<br>";
}

if(strpos($file[$i],'volume')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$volume= $cont[1];
echo $volume;
echo "<br>";
}

if(strpos($file[$i],'number')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$number= $cont[1];
echo $number;
echo "<br>";
}

if(strpos($file[$i],'pages')){
preg_match('/\"(.*?)\"/',$file[$i],$cont);             
$pages= $cont[1];
echo $pages;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
}
}

?>
```

Expected output (From above mentioned example):

```
Boonzaier, A. and Schubach, K. and Troup, K. and Pollard, A. and Aranda, S. and Schofield P.
Development of a psychoeducational intervention for men with prostate cancer
Journal of Psychosocial Oncology
27
1
136-153


Bottorff, J. L. and Oliffe, J. L. and Kelly, M.
The gender (s) in the room
Qualitative Health Research
22
4
435-440
```

Comment: What kind of file format is that? If this is some standardised format, there should exist parsers for it. If this is something of your own design, you should write a proper parser for it. Just a bunch of regexen may not work well at all here, depending on how the format is actually specified and what edge cases its syntax may have.

Comment: @deceze This is a bibliography file to create reference part in a journal,book etc. Just I need to get their values of article elements. When looping how to eliminate only book elements ?

Comment: post the exact output you want to get

Comment: Posted the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the reason your code captures `@book` elements is because you are not recording the line at which `@article` element is terminated. Thus, when you iterate over all the lines inside the `@article` element, you start at the line where your `@article` element starts and finish at the line where the next `@article` element starts.

There are two alternative ways to fix your code:

1. Record both the start and the end lines of the `@article` element, when you originally scan through all the lines in the file. For example:

   ```
   // count of article
   $key_start = '@article';
   $key_end = '}<br/>';
   foreach ($file as $l => $line) {
       if (strpos($line,$key_start) !== false) {
           $start = ++$l;
           next;
       }
       if (strpos($line,$key_end) !== false) {
           $typeart[] = array($start, --$l);
           next;
       }
   }
   // end-count of article
   ```

   Now you should be able to iterate over the lines belonging to the `@article` element by simply doing:

   ```
   for($j=0;$j<$counttypeart;$j++){
       list($start, $end) = $typeart[$j];

       for ($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++) {
       …
   ```
2. Break out from your second `for` loop early, as soon as you come to the @article's closing tag. Thus, avoiding iteration over all the lines up to the following `@article` element, eg:

   ```
   for($i=$typeart[$j];$i<$typeart[$j+1];$i++){
       $key_end = '}<br/>';
       break if (strpos($line,$key_end) !== false);
       …
   ```

However, neither of this solutions are ideal, as both of them results in the repetitive code which is difficult to maintain. Plus, it relies on you knowing each and every attribute within the `@article` element in order to capture its value. Unless you have a very good reason to structure your in this specific way, I would opt for an alternative solution…

**Alternative solution:**

1. read in all of the bibliography text at once
2. use regular expression to capture content of all `@article` elements
3. use another regular expression to capture parameter names and their values within captured content of individual `@article` elements

The following is a brief implementation of what I'm talking about:

```
<?php

// Use file_get_contents() instead of file() as it is the preferred way
// read the contents of a file into a string. It will also use memory mapping
// techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.
$file_content = file_get_contents('master.bib');

// Capture all article container from file content. We use a regular 
// expression on a multi-line string to do that:
preg_match_all(
    '%@article{\w+,<br/>\s+(.*)\s+}(<br/>)?%sUu',
    $file_content,
    $articles,
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
);

// Initialise empty results (plural) container which will store results data 
// for all @article elements
$results = array();

// At this point $articles[0] is an array of all captured @article blocks 
// and $articles[1] is an array of all captured first parenthesis within 
// the above regular expression.
foreach ($articles[1] as $article) {

    // Initialise empty result (singular) container which will store results
    // for the current @article element
    $result = array();

    // Now we will take the content of the first paranthesis, split it into
    // individual lines and pick out reqired data from those lines.
    foreach (explode("\n", $article) as $line) {
        $found = preg_match(
            '%\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*"?([^"]+)"?,?<br/>\s*%Uu',
            $line,
            $matches
        );

        // At this point $matches is populated with our desired data, unless
        // $found is 0 (no matches where found) or false (an error occurred)
        if ($found != false and $found > 0) {
            $result[$matches[1]] = trim($matches[2]);
        }
    }

    // Add current @article results to the list of all results, but avoid
    // doing so if current results are empty
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
}

// Print results
foreach ($results as $article) {
    print "{$article['author']}\n"
        . "{$article['title']}\n"
        . "{$article['journal']}\n"
        . "{$article['volume']}\n"
        . "{$article['number']}\n"
        . "{$article['pages']}\n"
        . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With some changes i got my code worked